# Set parameters of onMouse function manually in opencv

Tags: c++, events, opencv

I am using Opencv 2.4.2 in codeblocks in Windows 7. Basically I want to click on desired coordinates when some condition is true. This function extracts coordinates of left and right clicks.

All I want is to manually set the parameters of this function.
Its parameters involve event, x and y coordinates.

Following is the code I am using:

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)  
{  
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)  
    {  
        printf("LEFT CLICK\n");  
        printf("%d %d",x,y);  
    }  
    else if (event == CV_EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN)  
    {  
        printf("RIGHT CLICK\n");  
        printf("%d %d",x,y);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        printf("HOVER\n");  
        printf("%d %d",x,y);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I do not really get your problem... Why can't you call your callback function with your desired parameters?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I tried this:

setMouseCallback("image", onMouse(CV_EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN,9,98,0,"0"), 0);  

But it is showing error:
In function 'int main(int, char**)':
error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*'error:   initializing argument 5 of 'void onMouse(int, int, int, int, void*)'|  
error: invalid use of void expression